# NextJS does not compile typescript 5

Tags: typescript, next.js

I updated my typescript version to 5.0.2 but noticed that nextjs, which I believe is using SWC under the hood, is not transpiling the TS correctly, failing on a build error for TS 5 features.

Is there a way to update the next transpiler to use typescript version 5.

Example

```js
type fun = <const T>() => {};
```

terminal

```bash
tsc //compiles fine

...

next build
Error:
  x Expected ',', got 'T'
   ,----
 7 | type fun = <const T>() => {};
   :                   ^
   `----

Caused by:
    0: failed to process input file
    1: Syntax Error
```

#### What I've tried

##### Updating resolutions in package.json

```json
  "resolutions": {
    "typescript": "5.0.2"
  }
```

Comment: I think this is not possible

Comment: I used `yarn create next-app --typescript` to create a brand new app. It installed `"typescript": "5.0.2"`, so I'd say that at least with the latest version of Next, it should work. If it doesn't, I'd expect it to be fixed very soon because it's an issue that all new TypeScript projects will run into.